# How to decide the numbers of clusters based on a distance threshold between clusters for agglomerative clustering with sklearn?

Tags: cluster-analysis, distance, hierarchical-clustering

With `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering` from `sklearn` I need to specify the number of resulting clusters in advance. What I would like to do instead is to **merge clusters until a certain maximum distance between clusters** is reached and then stop the clustering process.

Accordingly, the number of clusters might vary depending on the structure of the data. I also do not care about the number of resulting clusters nor the size of the clusters but only that the cluster centroids do not exceed a certain distance.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scipy directly instead of sklearn. IMHO, it is much better.

Hierarchical clustering is a three step process:

1. Compute the dendrogram
2. Visualize and analyze
3. Extract branches

But that doesn't fit the supervised-learning-oriented API preference of sklearn, which would like everything to implement a `fit`, `predict` API...

SciPy has a function for you:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster

Answer (score 2):

This pull request for a `distance_threshold` parameter in scikit-learn's agglomerative clustering may be of interest:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9069

It looks like it'll be merged in version 0.22.

EDIT: See [my answer to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957258/709445) for an example of implementing single linkage clustering with a distance based stopping criterion using scipy.